# ValueError: numpy.ufunc has the wrong size, try recompiling

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, build, version

Got this error while using tensorflow 1.13.1 via conda.

End of Trace:

```
  File "__init__.pxd", line 872, in init tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util
ValueError: numpy.ufunc has the wrong size, try recompiling. Expected 192, got 216
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with **an old version of numpy** being installed on your system. In my case it turned out conda was selecting an incorrect version.

Solution:

```sh
pip uninstall -y numpy
```

then

```sh
pip install numpy
```

If you have multiple versions of numpy installed, you will get an error on the second step `Requirement already satisfied: numpy`. Repeat step 1 until you no longer get the error message.